# Is there a smooth Weyl equivariant map from this quotient space into $G_2/T^2$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, principal-bundles, exceptional-groups

It is known that $G_2$ acts transitively on $S^6$ with fibers $SU(3)$. Let us consider the following set $P$ of complex unitary $7 \times7$ matrices $A$, where

$$ A = (v_0, \, v_1, \, v_2, \, v_3, \, v_4, \, v_5, \, v_6) $$

so that $v_j$ is the $j$-th column of $A$, starting to count from index $0$, and such that

1. $v_0$ is real and
2. $v_{j+3}$ is the complex conjugate of $v_j$, for $j = 1, \ldots, 3$.

Define the map

$$\pi \colon P \to S^6$$

which maps $A \mapsto v_0$.

Note also that, by the remark at the beginning, $G_2$ can be thought of as the total space of a principal $SU(3)$-bundle over $S^6$, with bundle map say $\pi'$.

What I would like to know, ultimately, is the following. The group $H = U(1)^3$ acts on $A \in P$ as follows.

$$A \mapsto A \operatorname{diag}(1, \,\lambda_1, \, \lambda_2, \, \lambda_3, \, \bar{\lambda}_1, \, \bar{\lambda}_2, \, \bar{\lambda}_3).$$

> **Question.** Does there exist a smooth $W$-equivariant map from the
> quotient space $P/H$ onto the homogeneous space $G_2/T^2$, where $W$
> is the Weyl group of $G_2$ and $T^2 \simeq U(1)^2$ is a maximal torus
> in $G_2?$

I still have to define how $W$ acts on $P/H$ though. Define the following map

$$ \begin{align} 2e_1 - e_2 - e_3 & \mapsto v_1 \\
2e_2 - e_1 - e_3 & \mapsto v_2 \\
2e_3 - e_1 - e_2 & \mapsto v_3 \\
-2e_1 + e_2 + e_3 & \mapsto v_4 \\
-2e_2 + e_1 + e_3 & \mapsto v_5 \\
-2e_3 + e_1 + e_2 & \mapsto v_6 \end{align}$$

This is a one-to-one correspondence between the long roots of $G_2$ and the set of all columns of $A$ except for $v_0$. It is clear that $W$ acts on the set of long roots and so, via the map one-to-one correspondence above, $W$ also acts on the columns $v_1, \ldots, v_6$. This then descends to an action of $W$ on $P/H$.

Edit 1: here are some remarks. Given a fixed $v_0 \in S^6$, the span of $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ defines a $3$-dimensional complex vector space $E$. Moreover, $E \oplus \bar{E} \simeq \mathbb{C}T_{v_0}(S^6)$, where the latter is the complexification of the tangent space $T_{v_0}(S^6)$. Thus, such an $E$ defines an almost complex structure $J_E \colon T(S^6) \to T(S^6)$ which is compatible with the metric $g$ on $S^6$ coming from the Euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{R}^7$.

So the fiber of $\pi \colon P \to S^6$ defined above over a point $x \in S^6$ consists of pairs $(J_x, \, U_{(x,\, J_x)})$, where $J_x$ is an almost complex structure on $T_x(S^6)$ which is compatible with the inner product $g_x$, also defined on $T_x(S^6)$ and where $U_{(x,J_x)}$ is a unitary frame of $E_{(x,J_x)}$, where $E_{(x,J_x)}$ is the $i$-eigenspace of the complexification of $J_x$ actings on the complexified tangent space $\mathbb{C}T_x(S^6)$.

So $P$ consists of triples $(x, \, J_x, \, U_{(x,J_x)})$. Note that there is an intermediate bundle $Z$ over $S^6$, consisting of pairs $(x,\,J_x)$ which fibers over $S^6$ with fibers $SO(6)/U(3)$. What does $SO(6)/U(3)$ look like by the way, as a 6-manifold?

And $P$ fibers over $Z$ with fibers $U(3)$. So the dimension of $P$ is

$$ \dim(P) = 6 + 6 + 9 = 21$$

(which is interestingly also the dimension of $SO(7)$ actually).

Finally, if we consider the section $s$ of $F$ corresponding to the almost complex structure which comes from the cross product in $\mathbb{R}^7$ (itself stemming from thinking of $\mathbb{R}^7$ as being the imaginary octonions), then $P$ restricted to $s(S^6) \subset F$, which we will denote by $P|_{s(S^6)}$ is a bundle over $S^6$ with fibers $U(3)$.

Moreover, we have that $P|_{s(S^6)}/U(1)^3$ can actually be identified with $G_2/T^2$.

I have thus indicated where $G_2/T^2$ "lives", in this setting. By the way, if it turns out that the answer to my main question is "no", I would still be interested in knowing if there is some open subset $U \subset P$, which is preserved by the action of $W$ and such that there is a smooth $W$-equivariant map from $U$ into $G_2/T^2$. Your help is appreciated.